# Converting some code to vb.net from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I am converting some classes from `C#` to `VB.NET` and this line can't be converted properly.  I tried few online converters but they don't seem to work.

```
this.mGrid.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(RowDataBoundHandler);
```

Converted `VB.NET` that does not work.

```
Me.mGrid.RowDataBound += New GridViewRowEventHandler(RowDataBoundHandler)
```

The following are the two errors I am getting from that. Can anyone help me out coz my brain is dead now.

Thanks,

`Error  4   Delegate 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventHandler' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.   C:\My Projects\PMS\App_Code\GridViewHelper.vb   110 62  C:\My Projects\PMS\`

`Error  3   'Public Event RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.  C:\My Projects\PMS\App_Code\GridViewHelper.vb   110 9   C:\My Projects\PMS\`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `AddHandler` if you want to bind the event manually:

```
AddHandler Me.mGrid.RowDataBound, AddressOf RowDataBoundHandler
```

Or you can bind the event in the ASPX markup:

```
<asp:GridView ... RowDataBound="RowDataBoundHandler" runat="server" />
```

Or use Tim Schmelter's approach.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to register the event handler programmatically in VB.NET. You can either use the aspx markup to declare the event handler(`OnRowDataBound = "RowDataBoundHandler"`) or use the [`Handles` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx). You can even use one for multiple controls, separate them by commas.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) _
    Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
End Sub
```

If you want to add it manually anyway, use `AddHandler`:

```
AddHandler Me.GridView1.RowDataBound, AddressOf RowDataBoundHandler
```

Comment: Thanks Tim .. but I don't think I can use the way you suggested as that line of code is in class library than the web page itself.

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead, which is the VB way of doing this.  VB uses AddHandler to identify the event, and the AddressOf points to the delegate.

```
AddHandler mGrid.RowDataBound, AddressOf RowDataBoundHandler
```